# Which attribute is better for processing forms, name or id?

Tags: javascript

I'm working with forms and using fetch to post data. I usually use `id` to select elements, but I was thinking lately to use the `name` attribute instead. Is there some advantage for using the `id` attribute over the `name` attribute? Thanks.

For example

**HTML**

```
<form name="emailForm1">
  <input name="emailAddress1" type="email"><button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<br>
<form id="emailForm2">
  <input id="emailAddress2" name="emailAddress2" type="email"><button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
document.emailForm1.addEventListener('submit', emailSubmit1);

function emailSubmit1(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var email = e.target.emailAddress1.value;
  alert(email);
}

document.querySelector("#emailForm2").addEventListener('submit', emailSubmit2);

function emailSubmit2(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var email = document.querySelector("#emailAddress2").value;
  alert(email);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One benefit of `name` attributes is that they are included in the submitted form data by default. The code in your answer:

```html
<form name="emailForm1">
  <input name="emailAddress1" type="email"><button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

if you put `ab@a` in the field, results in a submission that ends in `?emailAddress1=ab%40a`. (Check your browser's Network tab to see.) As you can see, `emailAddress1` is included in the query string by default - this can make things a lot easier in some situations, when you want the user to be able to submit the form directly to the server, without having to send the request yourself with Javascript.

But if you're processing the fields on *frontend* only, or if you're always extracting field values and then sending a request manually, rather than submitting the form by default, then it doesn't matter - you can use any method to extract the values.

That said, global variables are highly discouraged, and IDs in the HTML always create global variables, so some might recommend using `name` attributes (or another method of selecting elements) instead when possible.

Comment: I would appreciate an explanation for the downvotes. If it was because someone thinks the question is too opinion-based to be answered, please reconsider - there *is* a clear advantage to using `name` attributes in certain situations.